# Run powershell commands from cmd / batch

Tags: powershell, cmd

I would like to run the following as **administrator**:

```
PowerShell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Command
.\Get-WindowsAutoPilotInfo.ps1 -ComputerName $env:computername
-OutputFile .\computers.csv -append
```

I would like to simply double click on a .cmd or .bat file and have it invoke the Powershell script as administrator. Here's what I have:

```
PowerShell "SL -PSPath '%CD%'; $Path = (GL).Path; SL ~; Start
PowerShell -Verb RunAs -Args \"-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Noexit"
SL -PSPath '"$Path"'; & '".\UninstallBloatware.ps1" "-ComputerName
$env:computername" "-OutputFile .\computers.csv" "-append"' "\""
```

I copied most of the code above from somewhere I can't remember. I don't know enough about quotes structure to know how to fix this. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I think your question is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/63569021/45375 (but cannot be marked as such, because the answer there doesn't have up-votes).

Comment: Making a .bat/.cmd will run anything in them (good or bad) via double click. Are you saying you tried this from a .bat/.cmd and it did not work? What errors did you get? Show, them. Quoting for such things is a well-documented/discussed topic. ['run PowerShell from a batch file'](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=%27run+powershell+from+a+batch+file%27&t=h_&ia=web)